# What would an erosion resistance ecological system look like?

Tags: evolution, xenobiology, geography, genetic-engineering, ecology

I was thinking about how given a whole host of sci-fi scenarios, you end up with landmass but no form of geological activity or plate tectonics, and so ensuring you end up with a lot of scenarios where you have constant erosion of existing landmasses and no existing or present method of replenishment, with the sole exception, in this case, being ecology. So the question, in short. Is this.

What would an ecological system look like as an entire whole whole as well as the individual organism that make up this system specifically engineered or ending up through evolution, as to prevent, be resistant to, or somehow reverse the erosion of existing landmasses?
Genetic engineering is allowed, the environment doesn't have to be based on earth biology or exist in an earth-like environment?

Comment: Wind erosion would be able to be accounted for by simply covering the surface in some form of vegetation, seemingly, as any surfaces worn down could end up replenishing, as being organisms, they'd end up, probabaly growing back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have various living things on earth that prevent erosion:

- [Mangroves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangrove#Ecology)
- [Corals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coral_reef#Shoreline_protection)
- [Ground Cover](https://www.popularmechanics.com/home/lawn-garden/how-to/a8911/3-ways-plants-can-help-you-control-erosion-15445641/)

Really anything with a root system or with the ability to create durable structures will help prevent erosion.

Now, *reversing* erosion is another issue.

The goal here will be to get dirt/soil out of the air. Blocking the wind (enough) will allow dirt to "drop out" and accumulate around/near the creature, reversing erosion in that small area. You can see this on some things like desert grasses- they occasionally can be found in small mounds of dirt.

Assuming these grasses/coral creatures accumulate in an area and they can colonize whatever dirt/soil drops out of the air, they really can make a mountain out of a molehill! (Over geologic time...).